# Comparing number strings - convert them first or compare without conversion?

Tags: java, list

I have a list of numbers L1 as strings (ex. "2443"). I have another list L2 like that. I have to compare each number in L1 with each in L2. L1 has about 20,000 numbers (many are repeated). L2 has about 600 numbers, all unique.

I cannot get L1 and L2 in any other format.

I want to know what is the best way to compare -

1. Convert all numbers to Long by Long.parseLong() and then compare ?
2. Compare as strings ?

Which will be more efficient ? I suspect it might be almost the same because in 1, we have to parse the strings. That is overhead.

**EDIT -**

I came up with an example. L1 is the list of Netflix customer_ID who watched Titanic (romance). L2 is the list of customer_ID who watched Shrek(animation). If at least 70% of L1 also watched Shrek, then recommend animated movies to them. Also, make a note that people who like romantic movies might also like animated movies. Silly example, but i think it might make sense.

Count number of element in L1, call it count. Then, we check if an element of L1 exists in L2. If true, increase 'found' by 1. Calculate found/count. If > 70%, recommend animated movies to romance lovers.

Comment: Compare and do what ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot - I am not sure that the purpose behind the comparison would be relevant in this case. I'd like to think of this as just a task.

Comment: Depends: do you want them in numeric order, or lexigraphical order?

Comment: Your two cases don't always behave the same though. What if elements differ in the number of digits?

Comment: @ZongLi - it is possible, but the possibility is low in my case.

Comment: @SuperStar , Why don't you try a sample case with both approaches and log the timings ?

Comment: @ZongLi: So you're saying all the numbers have exactly the same number of digits? That's the only case in which the results will always be the same.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought I was suggesting exactly the opposite? o.o

Comment: "Compare" as in "get order" or as in "equals"?

Comment: If you need a difference of lists or anything like that, you can use the HashSet<String>.

Comment: @ZongLi: Sorry, that was meant to be aimed at SuperStar instead, replying to his "possibility is low" statement.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot - how do i log the timings ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot - okay. I came up with an example. L1 is the list of Netflix customer_ID who watched Titanic (romance). L2 is the list of customer_ID who watched Shrek(animation). If at least 70% of L1 also watched Shrek, then recommend animated movies to them. Also, make a note that people who like romantic movies might also like animated movies. Silly example, but i think it might make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just code and check??

**TestCode**

**Case 1**

result `0.15` second; [see here](http://ideone.com/Xdr0qS)

```
class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
     String a = "1235";
     String b = "1235";

     for(int i = 0; i< 20000*600; i++){
         if(a.equals(b));
     }
  }
}
```

**case 2**

result `3.96` second [see here](http://ideone.com/hYmNej)

```
class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
     String a = "1235";
     String b = "1235";

     for(int i = 0; i< 20000*600; i++){
         if(Long.parseLong(a) == Long.parseLong(b));
     }
  }
}
```

**Note**

Tested in worst case (20000*600 loops). in best implementation you will need 600*log(20000) loops.

Comment: I just used that.. but you can check in your own ide using timer

Answer (score 2):

String comparison compares lexicographically: [see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).  This means, "1000" < "8000" < "900" according to the order set by `String.compareTo`.

So, better to convert to Integer, if you want the proper numerical order. You can use `Integer.parseInt(str)`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit of missing information here - do you ever need to convert these to a number? Are you only comparing equality? If the only point is equality comparison, and not actually getting the number as a Long then you are better off not converting to numbers:

With no conversion to number, in the worst case, you are reading each string L1 * L2 times. But in the average case a lot of these comparisons will be fast tracked since strings will differ in size / won't differ just on the last number.

With conversion to number you are forced to read every single string (L1 * L2 times) and then add the int comparison above that.

This becomes more complex if the input string is not guaranteed to be clean (can you get `" 2"` and `"2"`).

Running a quick, anecdotal, exercise which generates 2 random lists with numbers as strings shows that the string compare is substantially faster (numbers in ms, hits is the number of equal numbers):

```
Compare Strings: 249.0363 (hits: 600)
Compare with Convert: 2505.3822 (hits: 600)
```

This continues to repro across multiple runs.

Comment: Right now, only equality matters. I don't think i need to convert it to a long to use later.

Comment: I mocked this up and found that the String comparison is indeed much faster if equality is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

From the example can be deduced that you are comparing strings rather than numbers (an ID might be a number but because you will not be calculating with it, it makes sense to see it as a String).

Therefore I think you should use string-comparison to compare for equality rather than converting it to a number first. This solution is the more efficient.